# Replace text in file using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to replace varying items in a file. I need to replace: `/var/lib/cassandra/data`. How do I deal with the `/`?
I tried:

```
sed -i -e 's/var\/lib\/cassandra\/data\/var\/lib\/storage\/cassandra\/data/g' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

Result:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 65: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Is that a backtick or a quote you're using?

Comment: instead of 's/var\/lib\/cassandra\/data\/var\/lib\/storage\/cassandra\/data/g' use 's/var\/lib\/cassandra\/data/\/var\/lib\/storage\/cassandra\/data/g' - learn to count your slashes, mate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/rpc_address: localhost/rpc_address: 0\.0\.0\.0/g’ /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

You have inserted backtick after the global flag `g` instead of single quote. Just replace the backtick with single quote. Or copy paste the below command. And also there is no need for `-e` flag.

```
sed -i 's/rpc_address: localhost/rpc_address: 0.0.0.0/g' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

For the second one your command would be,

```
sed -i 's~var\/lib\/cassandra\/data~var\/lib\/storage\/cassandra\/data~g' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

I assumed that you are trying to replace `var/lib/cassandra/data` with `var/lib/storage/cassandra/data`. If you want to replace `/var/lib/cassandra/data` then here you go,

```
sed -i 's~\/var\/lib\/cassandra\/data~\/var\/lib\/storage\/cassandra\/data~g' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

Comment: Dang. My Mac text editor auto did that. I didn't notice.

Comment: Thanks again. This is better than uploading and copying the modified file, changing permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use escaping to escape the control symbols in those strings

```
sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

(this example changes single `/` to `\/`)

... **or** change sed's regexp delimiter.

Also, it seems you used backtick `` ` `` instead of `'`.

Comment: I tried: sed -i -e 's/rpc_address: localhost/rpc_address: 0\.0\.0\.0/g’ /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml

Comment: nb, you don't need to escape the dots in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to handle `/` with `sed`

```
sed  -e -i 's|/var/lib/cassandra/data|/var/lib/storage/cassandra/data|g' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

You can use any symbol as delimiter, just use one that is not int the data you have. like `|`